# C#: Drag & Drop with right mouse button

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I'd like to do Drag & Drop with the right mouse button instead with the left one. However calling

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop()
```

from MouseRightButtonDown instead of MouseLeftButtonDown doesn't do the job - DragDrop.DoDragDrop looks for mouse movements while holding down the left mouse button. Any idea how to realise Drag & Drop using the right mouse button? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of DragDrop.AddQueryContinueDragHandler(). Please see [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/16d1d0f7-5fa5-4845-a836-dab01aa575be) for details.